# Скрытый текст в reviews - раскрывать/скрывать их по клику кнопке далее / скрыть

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

Коллеги добрый день!

У меня задача такая:
в комментариях с отзывами у всех айтемов - при загрузки страницы нужно скрыть лишний текст (300 макс символ), после нужно раскрывать/скрывать их по клику кнопке далее / скрыть, отдельно по индексу - но тут контент загружается по ajax запросу на бэкенд , и при добавлении или обновлении контента по ajax, выше перечисленные инициализации не производятся, пожалуйста подскажите как решить такую проблему ?

желательно на библиотеке jQuery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]